# Interesting syntax error in c++ function using dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++

I'm working on a screen for a game using the basic Windows console.

Unfortunately I am getting this error

```
1>d:\users\chris\documents\programs\testing\roguelike mkii\roguelike mkii\screen.h(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '['
1>d:\users\chris\documents\programs\testing\roguelike mkii\roguelike mkii\screen.h(49): error C2337: 'pPoint' : attribute not found
1>d:\users\chris\documents\programs\testing\roguelike mkii\roguelike mkii\screen.h(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before '.'
1>d:\users\chris\documents\programs\testing\roguelike mkii\roguelike mkii\screen.h(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
```

and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Also in the setChar() function the pPoint.nX says that it must be constant which i can't understand.

```
struct pointOnScreen
{
    char character;
    int colour;
};
class Screen
{
private:
    const int xLength;
    const int yLength;


    pointOnScreen** screen;


public:
    Screen() : xLength(80), yLength(24)
    {

        screen = new pointOnScreen*[xLength];
        for(int ix = 0; ix < xLength; ix++)
        {
            screen[ix] = new pointOnScreen[yLength];
            for(int iy = 0; iy < yLength; iy++)
            {
                screen[ix][iy].character  = ' ';
                screen[ix][iy].colour = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    ~Screen()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < xLength; i++)
        {
            delete[] screen[i];
        }
        delete[] screen;
    }

    void setChar(char toSet, point pPoint)
    {
        pointOnScreen[pPoint.nX][pPoint.nY] = toSet;
    }



};
```

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Use a vector of vectors or a specialized matrix. Your class doesn't behave properly. Those would make it behave properly and let you get rid of your destructor to boot.

Comment: Thanks that was it just me using the struct instead of the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> pointOnScreen[pPoint.nX][pPoint.nY] = toSet;
> ```

`pointOnScreen` is a type, not a `variable`.

I guess you meant:

```
screen[pPoint.nX][pPoint.nY] = toSet;
```